# Need Help on TabActivity

Tags: android, tabactivity, activitygroup

I implement a TabActivity exactly like this -

```
http://blog.henriklarsentoft.com/2010/07/android-tabactivity-nested-activities/
```

Now the problem is, I have some Spinner in an activity. When i click to expand the Spinner - the following exception occur -

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@43b957c0 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

Anybody have solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error might be due to the context of your adapter, try giving getParent() as the context of the adapter instead of this.

[this](http://www.anddev.org/view-layout-resource-problems-f27/how-to-fix-this-windowmanager-badtokenexception-t16555.html) link will help you.

Comment: Not working. I think the problem arises when the spinner window is created. Try another guess please. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The Link contain useful content. I don't test yet. But have a question - Only a spinner is used to setContentView. and the spinner is created by LayoutInflater. But i already have the layout defined in xml. And get the spinner by findViewById. I don't know it'll work for me. But thanks for helping.

Comment: @Shaiful Its not the spinner that is set as the content,the xml is inflated using the inflater and set as the content.

Comment: Got the point. And everything working perfectly. Thanks for helping. :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that using "normal" layout inflation, the context used to inflate with is "this" which is the nested Activity. Unfortunately, an Activity nested inside a tab (an ActivityGroup) can't be used to show dialogs (I'm not exactly sure why that is, but it produces the BadTokenException). The solution I found most palatable is to not use setContentView(int id) but rather do explicit inflation using getParent() as the Context. Like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    View contentView = LayoutInflater.from(getParent()).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
    setContentView(contentView);
}
```